# Create a shortcut on the desktop that prompts before shutdown

Tags: vbscript, desktop, shortcut

I need to create a shortcut in which I can be prompted if I would like to shut down windows (Action to shutdown when clicking ok). Any ideas?

So far the working shutdown shortcut that I have does not issue the prompt a message asking if I truly want to shutdown or cancel the shortcut request.

Here it is:

```
Dim shellApp, answer

'Creates Shortcut with a Path to the desktop.
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
DesktopPath = Shell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

'Establishes and names the shortcut "Shutdown".
Set linkShutdown = Shell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\Shutdown.lnk")

'Adds shutdown code to the shortcut.
linkShutdown.Arguments = "-s -t 01"

'Adds Description to shortcut that displays message on link over.
linkShutdown.Description = "Shutdown this Computer"

'Creates Icon for shortcut using system shutdown icon.
linkShutdown.IconLocation = ("%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll,27") 

'Retrieves shutdown target path for shortcut.
linkShutdown.TargetPath = "shutdown"

'Saves the Script.
linkShutdown.Save

'Prompts the user if they want to shutdown their computer, 
'displays ok and cancel buttons for the user to choose.
Set shellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
answer = MsgBox("Do you really want to shut down the computer?", 1, _
         "Turn off Computer Script!")

If answer = 1 then
  Initiate_Logoff()
End if

'Function that shuts computer down.
Function Initiate_Logoff()
  'Adds shutdown code to the shortcut.
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyScriptPath 
MyScriptPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Call Shortcut(MyScriptPath,"Shutdown the computer")
Call AskQuestion()
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Shortcut(PathApplication,Name)
    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    MyTab = Split(PathApplication,"\")
    If Name = "" Then
        Name = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
    End if
    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\" & Name & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(PathApplication)
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll,-28"
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub AskQuestion()
    Dim Question,Msg,Title
    Title = "Shutdown the computer"
    Msg = "Are you sure to shutdown the computer now ?"& Vbcr &_
    "If yes, then click [YES] button "& Vbcr &_
    "If not, then click [NO] button"
    Question = MsgBox (Msg,VbYesNo+VbQuestion,Title)
    If Question = VbYes then
        Call Run_Shutdown(30)
    else
        WScript.Quit()
    End if
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Run_Shutdown(N)
    Dim ws,Command,Execution
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Command = "Cmd /c Shutdown -s -t "& N &" -c "& DblQuote("Save your work because your PC will shut down in "& N &" seconds")
    Execution = ws.run(Command,0,True)
End sub
'**********************************************************************************************
```